# sql data type - date OleDbSchema

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL Server 2012 table with a column named `X` and defined as `DATE`.

When I run `GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Columns,...)` the `DATE_TYPE` comes up as 130. I was expecting 133.

Can anyone please explain? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MSDN Using Date and Time Data:](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878(v=sql.105).aspx)

> Backward Compatibility for Down-level Clients
>
> Some down-level clients do not support the time, date, datetime2 and
>   datetimeoffset data types added in SQL Server 2008. The following
>   table shows the type mapping between an up-level instance of SQL
>   Server 2008 and down-level clients.

You see the 130 because of backwards copatibility

Comment: Thanks for your promptness.